# Delete a node from dynamic Binary Search Tree using iteration in C (Homework)

Tags: c, iteration, binary-search-tree

**Given:**

```
typedef int element;
typedef struct node
{
    element data;
    struct node *left,*right;
} *Btree;
typedef Btree BST;
```

**Write a recursive function that delete an element e from a BST. Return 0 if unsuccessful, 1 if successful.**

**You may use the following function in your code:**

```
BST *find(BST *B, element e) //didn't use it since I didn't find the need for it, although since it's given, it probably is useful
```

**My code:**

```
int delete_BST(BST *B , element e)
{
    if(!(*B)) return 0;
    BST t = *B;
    while(1)
    {
        if(t->data < e) t = t->right;
        if(t->data > e) t = t->left;
        else
        {
            if(t->left && t->right)
            {
                BST maxleft = t->left;
                while(maxleft->right)
                    maxleft = maxleft->right;
                t->data = maxleft->data;
                t = t->left;
                e = maxleft->data;
            }
            else
            {
                BST temp = t;
                if(!t->left) t = t->right;
                else if(!t->right) t = t->left;
                free(temp);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

**Input:**

```
    6
   / \
  3   8
 / \
1   5
Then delete: 1, 5, 8, -5, 0, 4 and 23
```

**Expected Result:**

```
  6
 /
3
```

**My Result:** *it's blank*

my approach to this was applying the previous recursive method and transforming it to be iterative
however that question had another given fucntion other than `BST *find(BST *B, element e)`, it had `BST *find(BST *B, element e)` which I used to get the maximum element in the left subtree of a node to be deleted that had 2 children.

**My Recursive Code:**

```
int delete_BST(BST *B , element e)
{
    if(!(*B)) return 0;
    if((*B)->data < e) return delete_BST(&(*B)->right, e);
    else if((*B)->data > e) return delete_BST(&(*B)->left, e);
    else
    {
        BST temp;
        if((*B)->left && (*B)->right)
        {
            temp = max_BST((*B)->left);
            (*B)->data = temp->data;
            delete_BST(&((*B)->left), temp->data);
        }
        else
        {
            temp = *B;
            if(!(*B)->left) *B = (*B)->right;
            else if(!(*B)->right) *B = (*B)->left;
            free(temp);
        }   
    }
    return 1;
}
```

so what's wrong with the iterative solution and how can i fix it?

Comment: You question includes the phrase "You may use the following function in your code:". Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Yes?, it's a practice question prewritten in Moodle

Comment: You need to do some debugging/troubleshooting. "delete: 1, 5, 8, -5, 0, 4 and 23" Do one of those, print the tree. See if it's what you expect, if not, trace through the code to see why it went wrong, move on to the next. Asking us to debug your code isn't really what SO is for.

Comment: What if one tries to delete a node that is NOT in the tree? "Thou shalt not follow the NULL pointer, for chaos and madness await thee at its end." The Ten Commandments of Henry Spencer...

Comment: Something that looks _off_, though I haven't really done a deep delve into your code, is having `if(t->data < e) t = t->right;` followed by `if(t->data > e) t = t->left;` Did you mean to use an `else` here? Both of these can theoretically be executed.

Comment: @chris I did forget the else, but also, if one is true doesn't that make the other one false?

Comment: Given that if the first condition is true, `t` gets modified, not necessarily. If you could treat `t` as an immutable, you'd be correct.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, it's a really wrong thing to put, but it works by accident since it'd rerun the loop and do that anyway